# Verifying convergence in probability and distribution.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Suppose random variables $\{X_n\}$ are defined on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ (where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure) as follows:
$X_1 = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}, X_2 = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1/2]}, X_3 = \mathbb{1}_{[1/2,1]}, X_4 = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1/3]}, X_5 = \mathbb{1}_{[1/3,2/3]}, X_6 = \mathbb{1}_{[2/3,1]}$, etc.

**Exercise:**

a) Verify that $X_n \stackrel{p}{\to} 0$

b) Verify that for any $w \in [0,1]$, $X_n \not\to 0.$

**Questions:**

- a) How do I show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}P(\left|X_n\right|>\epsilon)\to 0$? Intuitively it feels very clear that $X_n$ converges in probability: as $n$ goes to infinity the probability that the indicator functions is equal to $1$ goes to zero. I'm not sure however how to mathematically show this.
- b) What does $w$ do for our random variables? $X_n$ isn't dependent on $w$ right? So how can we write $X_n(w)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that your random variables are given as:

$$X_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j} = \mathbb{1}_{\left[\frac{j}{n}, \frac{j+1}{n}\right]}, \text{ for } j \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}, n\in\mathbb{N}$$

So for any $\varepsilon \in \langle 0, 1\rangle$ we have

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j}\right| > \varepsilon\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\mathbb{1}_{\left[\frac{j}{n}, \frac{j+1}{n}\right]} > \varepsilon\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\left[\frac{j}{n}, \frac{j+1}{n}\right]\right) = \frac1n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

For $\varepsilon \ge 1$ we have $\left\{\left|X_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j}\right| > \varepsilon\right\} = \emptyset$, so the probabilities also converge to $0$. Therefore, $X_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0$.

Take $w \in [0,1]$. Notice that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $X_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j}(w) = 1$ at exactly one or two $j \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$.

Namely, if $w \in \left\langle \frac{j_0}{n}, \frac{j_0+1}{n}\right\rangle$ for some $j_0$, then $X_{_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j_0}}(w) = 1$, and $X_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j}(w) = 0$ for every $j \ne j_0$. If $w = \frac{j_0}{n}$ for some $j_0$, then $X_{_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+(j_0-1)}}(w) = 1$, $X_{_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j_0}}(w) = 1$ and $X_{_{\frac{n(n-1)}2+1+j}}(w) = 0$ for every $j \notin \{j_0-1, j_0\}$.

We conclude that $X_n(w)$ cannot converge to $0$ because $1$ occurrs infinitely many times in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did say though that I don't understand what $X_n(w)$ means in the context of the exercise. While I see that you address the converge in distribution of $X_n(w)$, I still don't understand what $w$ or $X_n(w)$ means..

Comment: @titusAdam $X_n(w)$ is just the function $X_n$ evaluated at some point $w \in [0,1]$.

Comment: It would perhaps be clearer if stated like this: for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $f_n : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a measurable function defined as $f_n = \ldots$. Prove that for any $x \in [0,1]$, the sequence $(f(x))_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge to $0$. It has nothing to do with measure/probability.

Comment: I suspect you have $X_{n(n-1)/2+1+j} = \mathbb{1}_{\left[\frac{j}{n}, \frac{j+1}{n}\right]}$ but this only has notational effects on your argument

Comment: @Henry Yes, thanks.

Comment: @mechanodroid Thanks I think I get it. How did you manage to rewrite $X_n = X_{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1+j}$? I would have no idea how to get there. :p

Comment: @titusAdam Notice that $n$ as a denominator first appears at the position $1 + 2 + \ldots + (n-1) + 1$, because there is one term with denominator $1$, two terms with denominator $2$, three terms with $3$ and so on. The sum evaluates to $\frac{n(n-1)}2 + 1$. The denominator remains to be $n$ for exactly $n$ functions, starting from $\frac{n(n-1)}2 + 1$ and ending with $\frac{n(n-1)}2 + 1 + (n-1)$, while the numerators increase by $1$. Actually, this should be read as $X_n = X_{\frac{m(m-1)}2 + 1 + j}$, for unique $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $j \in \{0, \ldots, m-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

a) Note that

$P(x_n=1)=\frac{1}{k}$ for all $\frac{(k-1)k}{2}<n\leq \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.

Hence as $n\to\infty$ (because $k\to\infty$)

$P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\to 0$.

b) Here note that 
for any $w$,

$X_n(w)=1$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$.

Hence $X_n(w)\not\to0$.